# C++ template class compilation error

Tags: c++, class, templates

I get the following compilation error:

```
main.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':¶
main.cc:200: error: no match for 'operator==' in 'rt1 == rt2'¶
triple.hh:124: note: candidates are: bool Triple<T1, T2, T3>::operator==(const    Triple<T1,T2, T3>&) [with T1 = int, T2 = int, T3 = int] <near match>¶
main.cc:27: note:                 bool operator==(const Special&, const Special&)¶
```

Although I have implemented the operator== overload as follows for my template class:

```
bool operator==(const Triple<T1, T2, T3>& another) {
    return (a == another.first() and b == another.second() and c == another.third());
}
```

For my template class:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class Triple
```

Do you know what the problem might be? Many thanks.

Comment: What is `Special` class?

Comment: What are the types of `rt1` and `rt2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boolean operator is declared as non-const.  Fix it as follows in case `rt1` is a const reference.  Note the added `const` keyword.

```
bool operator==(const Triple<T1, T2, T3>& another) const {
```

Explanation: C++ has two basic syntaxes for overloading a comparison operator; a member operator with one other argument, or a static operator with two arguments.  However, in both cases, you should make sure that both operands are `const`, with the respective syntaxes.

It is theoretically possible to supply different `const` and non-`const` versions of the operator that do subtly different things, so the compiler calls yours a near-match, but nevertheless not a match.